# Inconsistent accessibility: property type User_smg is less accessible 'frmDashboard_smg.currUser'

Tags: c#

```
namespace Capstone_v._1
{
    public partial class frmDashboard_smg : Form

    {
        public User_smg currUser { get; private set; }

        public frmDashboard_smg()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            User_smg.InitializeDB();
        }
```

Comment: Your question does not seem to actually contain a question. Maybe you could rewrite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property currUser has public accessibility.
The error must be due to the type User_smg having a stricter accessibility where it is defined.

E.g it may be defined as

```
class User_smg
```

The default accessibility for class is internal (can only be accessed within the same assembly)
This can be made public with:

```
public class User_smg
```

As it is, your property is public so has no restriction on where it can be accessed from but the type is not to be exposed with no restriction (I.e it is not public) so it cannot be used with the public (unrestricted access) property.